# how to add driver for geo nodes property

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

I want to add a driver so that the Hue Value Affects the Z location of an external cube
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on hue in geometry nodes modifier -> copy data path

give your other object on z-location this driver:

[image]

paste your copied data path into path

result:

[image]